# Schema.org property for track number (music album)

Tags: schema.org, music

I'm in the process of creating a album-based webpage and now in the process of providing Schema.org annotations (using Microdata) for element as needed. The only element I'm having trouble labeling are the numeric representations of tracks, or **track number**.

I've searched through Schema.org's array of [options](http://schema.org/MusicRecording) for music records but had no luck finding anything. Is there a property that I'm overlooking that is best suited for numeric list values?

```html
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/MusicRecording">
  <div itemprop="track">
    <span>01</span> <!--Here's an example of what I'm referring to -->
    <span itemprop="name"">Track 1</span>      
    <time datetime="PT2M30S">2:30</time>
  </div>

  <div itemprop="track">
    <span>02</span>
    <span itemprop="name"">Track 2</span>      
    <time datetime="PT3M0S">3:00</time>
  </div>
  ...
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`MusicRecording` type](http://schema.org/MusicRecording) does not define a suitable property for the track number. I think this makes sense, because a recording could be released on different records, possibly with a different track number.

The [`MusicAlbum` type](http://schema.org/MusicAlbum) allows to reference an [`ItemList`](http://schema.org/ItemList) in the [`track` property](http://schema.org/track). An `ItemList` can reference [`ListItem`](http://schema.org/ListItem) items ([`itemListElement` property](http://schema.org/itemListElement)), and each `ListItem` can have a [`position` property](http://schema.org/position), giving the position "of an item in a series or sequence of items". I guess this could be used for the track numbers in an album.

However, the description of `MusicAlbum`’s `track` property says:

> If an ItemList is given, the list should contain items of type MusicRecording.

So they recommend to use `MusicRecording`, which can’t have the `position` property.

You could use both types, `MusicRecording` and `ListItem`, and provide the `position` property. This works fine with the syntaxes RDFa and JSON-LD, but it’s not allowed in the Microdata syntax (where you may provide multiple types, but you may not use properties that are not defined for all of these types; but many users seem to ignore this restriction).

Comment: So would the itemprop and itemscope be applied to the track number inline as so? `<span itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ListItem" itemprop="position">01</span>`

Comment: @CarlEdwards: No, the `position` property has to be a child, and each `ListItem` (which represents a track, possibly multi-typed with `MusicRecording`) has to be referenced with the `itemListElement` property, e.g.: `<div itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ListItem"><span itemprop="position">1</span></div>`.

Comment: Ah, thanks for clearing that up for me. Do you think going the extra mile in providing the additional `ListItem` scope would benefit the page in regards to page crawlability?

Comment: @CarlEdwards: I’m not sure in which way do you think it would have an effect on the crawlability? From my point of view, you’d have to decide which level of detail you want to provide in your structured data. If you *want* to include the track number, I think this is the only way that’s currenly possible with Schema.org.